# Message Parser C#

Tags: c#, list

I've been trying to make some kind of message parser, that gets only my sent messages. For example if i had message like that:

```
Viktor Bale (11 aug. 2016 13:20:56):
Hi! How are you?

Not Viktor Bale (11 aug. 2016 13:20:56):
Hi! Good! And you?

Viktor Bale (11 aug. 2016 13:20:56):
Me too! And this message has 
Two lines!

Not Viktor Bale (11 aug. 2016 13:20:56):
And this doesn't matter!
```

I need to get only messages written by `Viktor Bale`
here is code, that i tryed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.Count; i++) 
{ 
    if (wordsList[i].StartsWith(defaultName)) 
    { 
        while (!wordsList[i].StartsWith(dialName)) 
        { 
            messages.Add(wordsList[i]); 
        } 
    }    
}
```

`wordsList` is list of my messages, recieved from txt file and read by `ReadAllLines`
So messages above is just list.

`defaultName` is my name, and `dialName` is name of my interlocutor.

But when i launch it, my app simply freezes. How should i do that?

Comment: You never increment `i` in your `while` loop. So if it is true once, that loop runs forever. Or.. until you can't add more items to your messages list

Comment: You should debug your code. Than if you still can not find your infinite loop [edit] post with [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to increment `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.Count; i++) 
{ 
    if (wordsList[i].StartsWith(defaultName)) 
    {
        while (i < worldList.Count && !wordsList[i].StartsWith(dialName)) 
        { 
            messages.Add(wordsList[i++]); 
        } 
    }    
}
```

Edit: Added a safety bounds check.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid endless `while` loop, use this code instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.Count; i++) 
{ 
  if (wordsList[i].StartsWith(defaultName)) 
    { 
      if (!wordsList[i].StartsWith(dialName)) 
      { 
        messages.Add(wordsList[i]); 
      } 
    }    
}
```

**OR**

you can use something simpler to achieve desired behaviour:

```
foreach (var word in wordsList) 
{ 
    if (word.StartsWith(defaultName)) 
    { 
        messages.Add(word); 
    }    
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Not every line starts with the person's name, only the "header" lines. This solution won't work with the given input.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will never come to an end.

Perhaps you meant something like this? I've tidied up your code and made it simpler.

```
foreach (var words in wordsList) 
{ 
  if (words.StartsWith(defaultName) && !words.StartsWith(dialName)) 
  { 
    messages.Add(wordsList[i]); 
  }   
}
```

Comment: Not every line starts with the person's name, only the "header" lines. This solution won't work with the given input.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to select your messages using linq assuming  that each line begins with the name of the sender and the message does not include a line break.
e.g.

```
var myMessages = wordsList.Where(x => x.StartsWith(defaultName))
```

The application is crashing on your while loop which simply evaluates a condition infinity but never does anything to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to do that so:

```
public static string ExtractSenderName(string line) {
    var i = line.IndexOf('(');
    if (i == -1)
        return string.Empty;

    return line.Substring(0, i).Trim();
}

public static void Main (string[] args) {

    var messages = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (ExtractSenderName(wordsList[i]) == defaultName) {
            messages.Add(wordsList[++i]);
        }
    }

    foreach (var x in messages) {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://repl.it/Crlc)